# Edit update all schedules except primary key in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I wanna change all fields of a json object except 'pk' in DRF. I just need to keep one json data. When adding a new data ,this one should override existing data. Is there a way to do it with django ?

my *models.py*

```
class ClientUser2(models.Model):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class ClientNameSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ClientUser2
        fields = ('url','phone_number','name','status','pk')
```

my views.py

```
class ClientViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows messages to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = ClientUser2.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClientNameSerializer
```

and it's my api root

[api_root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nACtk.png)

Comment: What is the isssue ?>

Comment: Where is the field `url` defined/which model have that/why have you included that in serializer ?

Comment: @UmairMohammad I want to override json object that I have created. Because I should keep only one json object in DRF.

Comment: @UmairMohammad                                                                                                          `router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('system', SystemViewSet)
router.register('client', ClientViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # http://localhost:8002/api/<router-viewsets>
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
]` I am a new DRF user. I have seen some examples about DRF and i used them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to only retrieve and update models you can use `RetrieveUpdateApiView`

Reference : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveupdateapiview